# How to get the previous 10 lines and the last 10 lines at the same time by sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write an oracle sql query
I have data table like this:

```
Table A
no ID       Time
1 A001  9/27/2021 3:22:42 PM
2 A002  9/27/2021 3:25:58 PM
3 A003  9/27/2021 2:40:48 PM
4 A004  9/27/2021 2:40:44 PM
5 A005  9/27/2021 2:40:46 PM
6 A006  9/27/2021 2:40:51 PM
........................................

1000 A1000  9/27/2021 2:44:38 PM
1001 A1001  9/27/2021 2:44:47 PM
1002 A1002  9/27/2021 2:44:36 PM
1003 A1003  9/27/2021 2:44:40 PM
1004 A1004  9/27/2021 2:44:43 PM
1005 A1005  9/27/2021 2:43:57 PM
............................................
     A99999999999................................
```

and 1 more table like this:

```
Table B
No       ID                 Time
1       A03        9/27/2021 2:40:51 PM
2       A05        9/27/2021 2:44:36 PM
............................................
A999........................................
```

know that table B is definitely in table A.How can we get 10 rows above and 10 rows down from table A for each row in table B?.
currently I just use rank(), lag(), lead() and then join the 2 tables together but no desired result yet

Comment: when you say 10 rows above and 10 rows down, does that mean following the leftmost `no` column or following the `Time` column?

Comment: I want following the Time column

Comment: the time column is the time of the ID I want to get the previous 10 IDs and the following 10 IDs by time

Comment: Why don't you just do the following? Or have I misunderstood your goal?
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A
ON B.TIME BETWEEN (A.TIME - interval '10' second) AND (A.TIME + interval '10' second)

Comment: You understand table A like this: it is a history of login IDs over time. and table B also contains login IDs and times, but is incomplete. I want to get from A the previous 10ID and the following 10ID corresponding to each ID in the REMOVE table

Comment: "currently I just use rank(), lag(), lead() and then join the 2 tables together but no desired result yet". But... There's no any code in your question. Please, show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH JOINED_TABLES AS (
  SELECT "A".*, B."no" AS B_no
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "A"."Time") AS RN
  FROM "A"
  LEFT JOIN B ON "A"."ID"=B."ID"
)
, CENTRE_RNS AS (
  SELECT RN FROM JOINED_TABLES WHERE B_no IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT J."no", J."ID", J."Time", C.RN FROM JOINED_TABLES J
LEFT JOIN CENTRE_RNS C ON J.RN BETWEEN C.RN-1 AND C.RN+1
ORDER BY "no"
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20fbe/2)

You can edit the second last line to be -10 and +10

Comment: I want to get both the previous 10 lines and the following 10 lines so for each line on B side I should get 21 lines on A

Comment: what appears to be the issue? you have to edit second last line to be +/-10

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and analytic functions.

For example, if you wanted the window of 2 rows either side:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TableB b
       INNER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT no,
                id,
                time,
                rn - MAX(match) OVER () AS window
         FROM   (
           SELECT no,
                  id,
                  time,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) AS rn,
                  CASE
                  WHEN a.time = b.time
                  THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time)
                  END AS match
           FROM   TableA a
         )
       ) a
       ON (a.window BETWEEN -2 AND 2)
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA (no, ID, Time) AS
SELECT level,
       'A' || TO_CHAR(level, '000'),
       DATE '2021-09-27' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '3' SECOND
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;

CREATE TABLE TableB (no, ID, Time) AS
SELECT ROWNUM,
       ID,
       time
FROM   TableA
WHERE  no IN (6, 32);
```

The query outputs:

> | NO | ID | TIME | NO | ID | TIME | WINDOW |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A 006 | 2021-09-27 00:00:18 | 4 | A 004 | 2021-09-27 00:00:12 | -2 |
> | 1 | A 006 | 2021-09-27 00:00:18 | 5 | A 005 | 2021-09-27 00:00:15 | -1 |
> | 1 | A 006 | 2021-09-27 00:00:18 | 6 | A 006 | 2021-09-27 00:00:18 | 0 |
> | 1 | A 006 | 2021-09-27 00:00:18 | 7 | A 007 | 2021-09-27 00:00:21 | 1 |
> | 1 | A 006 | 2021-09-27 00:00:18 | 8 | A 008 | 2021-09-27 00:00:24 | 2 |
> | 2 | A 032 | 2021-09-27 00:01:36 | 30 | A 030 | 2021-09-27 00:01:30 | -2 |
> | 2 | A 032 | 2021-09-27 00:01:36 | 31 | A 031 | 2021-09-27 00:01:33 | -1 |
> | 2 | A 032 | 2021-09-27 00:01:36 | 32 | A 032 | 2021-09-27 00:01:36 | 0 |
> | 2 | A 032 | 2021-09-27 00:01:36 | 33 | A 033 | 2021-09-27 00:01:39 | 1 |
> | 2 | A 032 | 2021-09-27 00:01:36 | 34 | A 034 | 2021-09-27 00:01:42 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f85768c299ae8106496a4060abfc6ff)*